# Почему не запускается сервис?

Tags: python, service, bottle

Написал приложение на python на фраймворке bottle.
Пытаюсь его запустить как сервис:

```
[Unit]
Description=project
After=multi-user.target
 
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/project/server.py
Restart=on-abort
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Как в [этом](http://www.diegoacuna.me/how-to-run-a-script-as-a-service-in-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie/) примере но на этом месте:
sudo systemctl enable hello.service
пишет
Failed to enable unit: File project.service: Invalid argument

Как его запустить?

```
Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2019-10-04 21:46:02 UTC; 52min ago
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 2361)
   CGroup: /project.service

Oct 04 21:46:02 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: A service for a web server that handles remote controlled outles...
Oct 04 21:46:02 ip-172-31-34-215 project.sh[31915]:  * Starting system project daemon
Oct 04 21:46:02 ip-172-31-34-215 project.sh[31915]:    ...done.
Oct 04 21:46:02 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: Started LSB: A service for a web server that handles remote controlled outles.
Oct 04 21:53:37 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/project.service:4: Missing '='.
Oct 04 22:07:46 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/project.service:4: Missing '='.
Oct 04 22:07:56 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/project.service:4: Missing '='.
Oct 04 22:08:45 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/project.service:4: Missing '='.
Oct 04 22:09:10 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/project.service:4: Missing '='.
Oct 04 22:09:21 ip-172-31-34-215 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/project.service:4: Missing '='.
```

Comment: Запустить — start, а enable не запускает, а добавляет в автозагрузку. Покажите systemctl status для вашего юнита

Comment: @andreymal обновил вопрос

Comment: Ну для начала бы `Missing '='` исправить. Попробуйте `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` и потом снова enable

Comment: @andreymal попробовал не помогло. Не понимаю, в чем ошибка. потому что все взял из примера

Comment: У меня ровно точно такая же ситуация. Было даже мнение, что это какой-то баг systemd. Система Ubuntu 18.04. Выполнял по [этой](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-5-%E2%80%94-creating-a-systemd-unit-file) инструкции Служба благополучно запускается, но не добавляется в автозапуск.
Появилось ли решение?

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли у пользователя, от имени которого systemd запускает сервис, доступ к папке проекта